# that helping him

Tags: word-meaning

I have run into this sentence and I am wondering what is the meaning of the phrase *that helping him*?

> X visited many countries and met a lot of people, that helping him much in his writing.

I thought it has to be *which helped him* instead.

Comment: You're right. Whoever wrote the sentence you came across probably doesn't know English very well.

Comment: *That* here is not a relative pronoun but a **demonstrative pronoun**, as in *Look at **that**!*  It is the subject of an **absolute construction**; you may find out more about those by clicking [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute-clauses). As @FumbleFingers suggests, this is an unusually clumsy use of the absolute clause; but almost all uses of the absolute clause are pretty clunky.

Comment: @StoneyB I was thinking that it is the contracted version of **that it is helping**

Comment: @Cardinal No, that wouldn't be grammatical.

Comment: @StoneyB: In principle you could make out a case for the cited text being "grammatical", but to my mind it's such awkward phrasing it would be easier to simply dismiss it as invalid. If I were *forced* to use the construction I think I'd at least change ***that*** to ***this*** (but I'd take some forcing! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers To my mind, everybody (including native speakers) should be taught to recognize absolute clauses so they can stamp them out ruthlessly.

Comment: @StoneyB: [*An Afghan refugee kisses the genitals of his eighteen-month-old son as a way of showing his affection, **this being a common practice** in his society.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22affection+this+being+a+common+practice%22) Putting aside the semantics, I can live with the *syntax* there (but per above, I'm much less keen on ***that*** in such constructions).

Comment: I found it in a reading passage of a test.

Comment: I'm not surprised; that's exactly the sort of rubbish people put in tests. I suppose it's justifiable: unhappily, there's a lot more bad English than good English, so if you're going to do much reading in English you have to learn how to read rubbish, too.

Comment: I enjoy reading the masters' comments. Interesting comments. :x:x

Comment: @StoneyB If this one were a 4-choice question, I would not choose _that helping him_ but it is not a question. It is a sentence in a reading passage and test makers often quote some passages from an article written by a native speaker. I just don't understand why he/ she had to come up with a sentence by himself/ herself as non-native speakers might make some mistakes (like this one).

Comment: It's not a mistake; it's just very clumsy.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for your suggestion. I have just checked the term **Absolute Construction**.

Comment: I think this is the original (Google returned 5 results for me, all pointing to the same text, but with variation in spelling): *One of the first novels in the history of literature was Robinson Crusoe, which Daniel Defoe, the great English writer, wrote in 1718 when he was nearly sixty years old. Daniel Defoe was born in London in the family of a rich man. ... Defoe visited many countries and met a lot of people, that helped him much in his writing.* Judging from some choices in the passage, it wasn't written by a native speaker. A version with *that helping* spells *nearly* as *nearby*, BTW.

Comment: @DamkerngT. What do you think about the term **Absolute Construction** as mentioned above?

Comment: @HồQuangTrung Even though it may be possible, I don't think it was intended, considering the rest of the text.

Answer (score 2):

> X visited many countries and met a lot of people, that helping him much in his writing.

*That* is a demonstrative pronoun. The word *that* refers to the actions mentioned in the independent clause. You can rewrite the sentence and use *that* as a demonstrative adjective:

> X visited many countries and met a lot of people, that experience helping him much in his writing.

The word *experience* is just an attempt to describe the actions of the main clause. One could also use other nouns, such as *process*.

The demonstrative pronoun *this* might sound better than *that*, since you have only now informed the reader of the experience or process.

Compare this to your suggested version:

> X visited many countries and met a lot of people, which helped him much in his writing.

*Which* is a relative pronoun. Yet it can sometimes be used to modify a noun while serving the same function in the sentence:

> X visited many countries and met a lot of people, which experience helped him much in his writing.